# how do i insert a huge amount of data rows from a CSV to MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have an Excel document (15KB) extracted as `.CSV` from a monitoring platform that uses 1 column **ip address** but contains **1048576** Rows.

- *how do I insert all this data in my MYSQL database?*

also, I have 10 of these excel documents each document maximizes the excel total rows. 
so I have a total of **10485760** rows to insert.

- *is MYSQL the appropriate database to use?*

I need to check these data from time to time, but im not sure where to store them and look/search for a specific row easily when I need to.

p.s: I don't work for the NSA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is you have to open your command prompt, and then type:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then type the password. After that use your desired database like this:

```
use (yourdatabase);
```

and then type this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\folder\\Filename.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I always use this when inserting very huge rows in mysql

Comment: after entering the above code, i get this `->` symbol. not sure what i miss here.

Comment: thank you for this, what i did was to paste the code inside my `PHPMYADMIN` SQL tab instead of typing it on my cmd :) thanks